# How to use a variable in the address of the Range method

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

How can I set variable in `Range`? This is my code:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Dim value As String
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("R3").Select
    value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("R3").value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("C:value").Select '<--- Here is the BUG
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read this [answer on how to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1), you do not need those select/activate 99% of the time. (In fact, it is bad practice)

Comment: Hello Raymond, thanks for the informations. I promise I will :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ranges the format is:
startColumn & StartRow & ":" & EndColumn & EndRow
EndColumn and EndRow are optional is not specified then they will be the same as Startcolumn and StartRow
for example to reference a range from column A, row 1 to Column D, Row 20 use:

```
sAddress = "A1:D20"
```

Comment: Thanks for informations. But I have a question. How can I declare variable in this range?

Comment: for example you would use:

sAddress = "A1:D20"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range(sAddress).Select

is the same as:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("A1:D20").Select

or:
sAddress = "R3"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range(sAddress).Select

is the same as:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("R3").Select
if this helps you, mark it as thumps up, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Untested**

Consider:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim valuee As String

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("R3").Select

valuee = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("R3").value

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("C" & valuee).Select

Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("C" & valuee).Select <--------- Here is Bug again. I don't have any ideas how to correct it.